# Menú no se abre cuando es necesario

Tags: javascript, html

Trato de hacer que mi menú se abra en la pagina web cuando este llegue a una medida de 450px, pero no realiza ninguna acción, este es mi código:

```html
  <header>
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo1.png">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Acerca de</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="boton" href="#"><button>Contactame</button></a>
        <a onclick="openNav()" class="menu" href="#"><button>Menu</button></a>
    </header>
    <body>
        <a onclick="openNav()" class="menu" href="#"><button>Menu</button></a> 
        <div id="menu__mobil" class="overlay">
            <a class="cierre" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay__content">
                <a href="#">Servicios</a>
                <a href="#">Proyectos</a>
                <a href="#">Acerca de</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/BarrasNavs/Barra1/main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Creo que el error se encuentra en el script:

```js
    function openNav() {
       document.getElementById["menu__mobil"].style.width="100";
    }
    function closeNav() {
       document.getElementById["menu__mobil"].style.width="0";
    }
```

Comment: Hola, evita porfavor las mayusculas en lo posible, son mal vistas en la comunidad, a algunos usuarios les molesta que usen mayusculas, según ellos parece como si estuvieses gritando, no les quito la razón...

Comment: Creo que no funciona porque cada vez que das click a un elemento <a> te redirige haciendo que no veamos cambio alguno, ademas esa no es la forma en la que se usa document.getElementById, se usan parentesis, no corchetes.

Answer (score 0):

En el código hay un error, la activación del evento , está asociada al evento click, cuando debe ser aplicado el evento `onresize` , aquí hay un ejemplo, con la captura de los pixeles en anchura y en altura, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onresize , entonces al obtener el valor en <= 450px , activa openNav() , si > 450 , `closeNav()` , hay que quitar los `onclick`, y colocar el `onresize` en la etiqueta body, como se explica en el link. y construir un condicional `if(w <= 450){ openNav(); }else { closeNav()}` , también puede mejorar su código, haciendo uso de la propiedad CSS diaply:block; y display:none, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, también puede consultar mediaqueries de CSS3

Comment: Si bien esto soluciona el problema por medio de javascript,  en lo que a rendimiento y acortabilidad de codigo se refiere hay una mejor opcion,  y es usando CSS.